# Trouble with CSRF token in Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Im trying to make registration page for users, but taking errors from Django (v 1.7.1):

> Reason given for failure:
>       CSRF cookie not set.

Im sure, that cookie allowed on my PC (chrome browser). Adding {% csrf_token %} doesn't solve my issue. Maybe somebody advise me, how to fix this trouble?

part from my register.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="." class="form-signin" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Register new user</h4>
        {{ form.login }}
        {{ form.login.errors }}
        {{ form.password }}
        {{ form.password.errors }}

        {{ form.address }}
        {{ form.address.errors }}
        {{ form.phone }}
        {{ form.phone.errors }}
        {{ form.postcode }}
        {{ form.postcode.errors }}

        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.email.errors }}
        <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary" type="submit">Register me</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

RegisterForm.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django import forms

from mainws.models.User import User

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    login = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=50, required=True,
                            error_messages={'required': 'Enter login'},
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'login',
                                                          'class': "input-block-level"}))
    password = forms.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=50, required=True,
                               error_messages={'required': u'Enter password'},
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'password',
                                                             'class': "input-block-level",
                                                             'type': 'password'}))
    address = forms.CharField(min_length=5, max_length=255, required=True,
                              error_messages={'required': u'Enter address'},
                              widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'address',
                                                            'class': "input-block-level"}))
    phone = forms.CharField(min_length=7, max_length=25, required=True,
                            error_messages={'required': u'Enter phone'},
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'phone',
                                                          'class': "input-block-level"}))
    postcode = forms.CharField(min_length=2, max_length=25, required=True,
                               error_messages={'required': u'Enter postcode'},
                               widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'postcode',
                                                             'class': "input-block-level"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(min_length=5, required=True,
                             error_messages={'required': u'Enter email'},
                             widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'email',
                                                           'class': "input-block-level"}))

    def clean(self):
        super(RegisterForm, self).clean()

        typed_login = self.cleaned_data['login']
        if User.objects.filter(login=typed_login).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This user already registered!')
        return self.cleaned_data
```

RegisterController.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic.base import View
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

from mainws.forms.RegisterForm import RegisterForm


class RegisterController(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = RegisterForm()
        return render_to_response('user/register.html', locals())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
            return HttpResponse('OK!', locals())
        else:
            return HttpResponse('all not valid!', locals())
```

Comment: Did you add `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`?

Comment: The error message is *absolutely* clear about what steps you need to take in your view to fix this. But in any case, why are you using a bare View, rather than a view with the form mixin, which would take care of this for you?

Comment: @dan-klasson I'll checked it. Its added by default when creating project viw django-admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake that you don't use RequestContext in `render_to_response`. That's is why csrf_token is empty.

To take advantage of CSRF protection in your views, follow these steps:

1. Add 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. **Done**
2. Use the csrf_token tag inside the  element. **Done**
3. Ensure that the 'django.core.context_processors.csrf' context processor is being used:
   use RequestContext in your's view or do it manually. **Not done**

More about this see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#how-to-use-it).